# Comprobar si han pasado X días desde una fecha insertada en una BD

Tags: php

Si tengo dos fechas en este formato:
(generadas con `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`)

`$fecha1 = '2017-01-12 17:39:25';`

`$fecha2 = '2017-01-19 17:39:25';`

Y quiero saber si `$fecha2`es 5 días más tarde que `$fecha1`

como puedo hacerlo?

Haciendo esto:

```
$fecha1 = strtotime('2017-01-12 17:39:25');

$fecha2 = strtotime('2017-01-19 17:39:25');
$secs = $fecha1 - $fecha2;
```

me da un resultado negativo.

Comment: te da negativo porque `fecha1 <  fecha2`

Comment: vale fallo mio...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al ser `String` has de pasarlas a `Fecha`

```
$time1 = strtotime($fecha1);
$time2 = strtotime($fecha2);
```

Despues las restas

```
$secs = $time2  - $time1 ;// == devuelve los segundos de diferencia
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

Tienes que despues de restar, dividir entre `86400` (para pasar segundos a días)

Output `$days`:

`7`

`$days > 5` - > ya tienes tu condición.

Comment: He puesto mal el enunciado. la las variables de la fecha están entre comillas: $fecha1 = '2017-01-12 17:39:25'; con lo cual no se pueden restar... o no es así?